# Software testing certification to start with?

Tags: testing

I am a programmer moved from Programming to Testing field. Its been one year since I am in Software testing field. I would like to know the certification which I can start with for Software testing and which is valuable in USA.

P.S: I am looking for a beginner level certification for now.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions, I'm afraid. It's not for career advice. :-) If you have future questions that are within the [help] guidelines, please come back and ask, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend ISTQB Software Testing Certification. It is the most popular testing certification in the US, as well as globally (over 300,000 have been certified globally). The entry level ISTQB certification is the Foundation Level.  There are also Advanced and Expert Levels as you continue your career.

One of the nice things about the ISTQB certification is the the body of knowledge (syllabus) and glossary are free to download.  You can then self-study or choose a training provider.  The US website for ISTQB certification is at http://www.astqb.org - that's the American Software Testing Qualifications Board.  The free syllabus and glossary are at http://www.astqb.org/get-certified/istqb-syllabi-the-istqb-software-tester-certification-body-of-knowledge/.  You'll find the information useful as a software tester.

Hope this helps!